# How to change the boot logo, Not the bootanimation 4.2.2

Tags: custom-roms, boot, bootloader, images

Im trying to find out if I can change the boot logo, the one that shows up right before the bootanimation. Currently it show's me a linux logo.

I am looking to either completely remove it or change it to something else, but I can not find any information related to this, all that comes up is the animation, which I honestly couldn't care less about.

So to summarize it, Can I change/remove the boot logo? If so, how?

Comment: Search web about flashing LOGO partition and/or flash/create/modify `logo.bin` for Android. Also use the term "boot logo" instead of boot animation when querying.

Comment: @Rose If your phone is powered by a Mediatek chipset, then use this tool to edit your boot logo: **[Boot *logo.bin* Builder](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1953726)**