# How to edit splash.img which displays the boot logo in Snapdragon chipset devices?

Tags: boot, editing

As far as I know, most devices powered by Snapdragon Chipsets stores the boot logo (splash screen that shows up when device is switched ON) in a partition named 'splash' which contains ***splash.img***

Is there a way to edit the splash.img file or create a new one?

**Additional Info:**

It seems there is some script/software for HTC phones to edit the splash image, but it seems it will set the image (picture) resolution to that of HTC phone's resolution.

My device is: Yu Yuphoria

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the boot logo, Not the bootanimation 4.2.2](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/131706)

Comment: @Firelord, The device of the OP has a mentioned Android version of 5.1.1. I suppose that it cannot be treated as a duplicate of your linked question

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury Android version is irrelevant here. Splash/boot image/logo is not dependent on the OS. So, it is perfectly a duplicate. Bootanimation, however, may very much be dependent on Android version.

Comment: @Firelord, even then, the linked question doesn't have an answer. Maybe we could request the mods to merge the 2? (and get on with some research?)

Comment: @Firelord I have specifically mentioned that it's splash.img for Snapdragon devices, unlike logo.bin (which is for Mediatek devices, [asked by that question's OP which you have linked](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/131706))

Comment: logo.bin is found in my standard Snapdragon 801 too. It's a OnePlus One.

Comment: @Firelord Oh I didn't know that :/  So, maybe boot logo is independent of the SOC.

Comment: I later found out how, and created splash.img for a few devices.. [**\[GUIDE\] How to Create Custom Boot Logo (splash.img) for Snapdragon Devices**](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software-hacking/guide-how-to-create-custom-boot-logo-t3470473)